# Stack Pop is not working with self made stack definition using LinkedLists

Tags: c++, stack, singly-linked-list

The pop function for my stack is not working. I am including the code for the pop function. I know that I could use the stack library in C++ but I am wanting to make my own to understand it better. It is not deleting the nodes in the stack and not pulling the double correctly. Everything else with the stack works fine.

```
double Stack::Pop()
{
   assert(!IsEmpty());

   double  n = topPtr.FirstNode();
   topPtr.DeleteNode( n );
   return n;
}
void LinkedList::DeleteNode( double x )
{
nodeptr prev, curr;

curr = start;

while( curr != NULL && x > curr->info )
{
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
}

if( x == curr->info )
{
    if( curr == start )
        start = start->next;
    else
        prev->next = curr->next;

    delete curr;
    count--;
}
}

//Below is where I use the pop function
roperand = rpnStack.Pop();
loperand = rpnStack.Pop();
cout << loperand << "  <Left      Right>  " << roperand << endl;
switch (op){
    case 0:
        answer = loperand + roperand;
        cout << answer << endl;
        rpnStack.Push(answer);
        break;
    case 1:
        answer = loperand - roperand;
        rpnStack.Push(answer);
        break;
    case 2:
        answer = loperand * roperand;
        rpnStack.Push(answer);
        break;
    case 3:
        answer = loperand / roperand;
        rpnStack.Push(answer);
        break;
            }

//This is the output I am getting

Please enter equation >> 5.5 5.5 +
Equation entered: 5.5 5.5 +
5<Left      Right>5
10
Below is what is left in the stack.
10
5.5
5.5
```

The 5 Left and Right 5 should both be 5.5 and popped out of the stack but they are staying in and the values being pulled are 5 not 5.5. All variables are of type double.

Comment: Add some more of the code, so we can see the issue

Comment: Your `if ( x == curr->info )` requires that `curr` not be `NULL`. But the `while` loop right above it tests if `curr` is `NULL`. That doesn't make sense. If `curr` must not be `NULL` upon exiting the `while`, why is `curr` being `NULL` an exit condition for the `while` loop?!

Comment: I figured it out, it was in the first node function, it was set to a int type. Switched it to a double type and it works now!